# Need random virtual keyboard in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i need a virtual keybopard to be displayed when user selects an option as use virtual keyboard. This keyboard should be generated randomly for each time i selects the option

Comment: What do you mean by "generated randomly"?  Do you want the letter positions jumbled?

Comment: Ya . For security purpose i want the virtual keyboard where keys should be displayed randomly.

Comment: @Dorababy You can get any javascript keyboard, and then just mix up the characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial describes how to create a virtual keyboard with several layout options.  You could adapt it to serve one of several pre-generated randomised keyboads, or with a bit more work, generate a truely randomised keyboard each time.

- **[JavaScript Virtual Keyboard](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jvk.aspx)**

I have to say, this sounds like it would be a proper pain to use.  People are used to one keyboard layout usually, and it would take ages to enter a long text string with it.  I find even alphabetical text entry system like our local car park ticket machines to be nearly unusable, and that's only entering 3 letters.

I hope for the sake of your user's sanity you're only going to want them to enter half a dozen characters at most!

Answer (score 1):

One more idea

This javascript keyboard is made out of **css** and javascript just get read clicks.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery/

**The only think that you have to do, is to randomize the characters when you render it.**

Then on the click the script just get whats you click on