# How do we create virtual keyboard for banking applications?

Tags: c#, javascript, html

could any explain me how to load the virtual keyboard for banking applications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need random virtual keyboard in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554877/need-random-virtual-keyboard-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it like as in below image than following link provide more idea about it.

[image]

[JavaScript Virtual Keyboard](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jvk.aspx)

Note: It's difficult to post whole code here so it's better you follow the post and do the changes according to it.